# Route is not commited in react

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have the route like this

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path='/' component={TopContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Login} />
            <Route path='main' component={MainContainer} /> 
            <Route path='second' component={SecondContainer} /> 
        </Route>        
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and I like to jump to the second and used

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/#second');

The result was that the browser address field was filled with       
"http://localhost:3000/#second" but the page did not move-to/show 
"http://localhost:3000/#second" and still stay at the same page.
Now, if I hit enter key on the browser address field it then 
show/move-to the right page (http://localhost:3000/#second).
```

What was wrong?

thanks

Comment: why do you have a `#` before `second`?

Answer (score 1):

The # is not part of the url. It is added by the `history` you are using. Also you are using `browserHistory` to push but not using it as the app's `history`.

Make these changes

```
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={TopContainer}>
            <IndexRoute component={Login} />
            <Route path='main' component={MainContainer} /> 
            <Route path='second' component={SecondContainer} /> 
        </Route>        
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Change `history` to `browserHistory`

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
browserHistory.push('/second');
```

Then use this for pushing to the `second` page

Answer (score 1):

The history that works with the `#` is the `hashHistory`. It works for addresses like this: http://localhost:3000/#/second

Use the `browserHistory` for address like this: http://localhost:3000/second

[You can find more information on react-router-tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/02-rendering-a-route)